# Writing commands with a specific colour

Tags: terminal, colors

I use the terminal and want to use a specific colour when writing commands.

For instance, suppose I write "history" on the command-line.  I would
like that the commands entered from the keyboard are colourised with a predefined colour.

In summary, all the commands entered by the user will show with the same colour.

[image]

Thus

```
history

grep -hir -C 8 "hello world" .
```

will show in blue.

Currently I have the following for PS1

```
PS1='\n\[\033[01;36m\]\u@\h:'
PS1=$PS1'\n+ \[\033[38;5;214m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n'
```

Then I did the following

```
OPS0="$PS0" OPS1="$PS1"
t7="$(tput setaf 7)" t5="$(tput setaf 5)"
[[ -n "$PS1" ]] && PS0="\[$t7\]" PS1="\[$t7\]$PS1\[$t5\]"
```

I get two strange characters at the beginning, just before 01cuneus

```
pete@home:~$ ls
01cuneus  Admir          Documents   logs      Public
02chaos   conjgrad.f90~  Downloads   Music     temp
03marshl  Desktop        fontconfig  Pictures  Videos
```

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question with [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/655858/100397)

Comment: This is somewhat different.  The other referred to using echo.  Now I am using printf and set a colour.  In this question, I want to colourise the commands I write.  Seppose I am in a terminal anh input the command "history" and want to use a particular colour.  I would not be using echo in this case but a simple input from the keyboard.

Comment: OK. I think you need to be far clearer in this question what it is you're looking for. Or did you mean `echo hello; tput setaf 4; echo world; tput setaf 7`

Comment: Yes you can use echo that way, using tput.  But here I want to ask about inputting commands with a different colour.

Comment: Have now put an example

Comment: Having all user written commands in one colour (e.g. blue) is enough.

Comment: What are the two strange characters you can see? There's nothing obviously wrong with what you're showing us

Comment: They are two boxes with strange characters in them, but which do not show when I copy them here.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for `bash` will lead you to the section on variables related to prompting. We are interested in these

> - `PS0` The value of this parameter is expanded and displayed by interactive shells after reading  a command and before the command is
>   executed.
> - `PS1` The  value of this parameter is expanded and used as the primary prompt string.

Both variables reference the later section on PROMPTING, which has these two markers for use within a prompt string

> - `\[` begin  a sequence of non-printing characters, which could be used to embed a terminal control sequence into the prompt
> - `\]` end a sequence of non-printing characters

Finally, the `tput` command references `terminfo`, which has these sections about colours

> - `setab` Set background color to #1, using ANSI escape
> - `setaf` Set foreground color to #1, using ANSI escape

and

> The `setaf`/`setab` [...] capabilities take a single numeric argument each. Argument values 0-7 of `setaf`/`setab` are portably defined as follows [...]
>
> ```
> Color       #define       Value     RGB
> black     COLOR_BLACK       0     0, 0, 0
> red       COLOR_RED         1     max,0,0
> green     COLOR_GREEN       2     0,max,0
> yellow    COLOR_YELLOW      3     max,max,0
> blue      COLOR_BLUE        4     0,0,max
> magenta   COLOR_MAGENTA     5     max,0,max
> cyan      COLOR_CYAN        6     0,max,max
> white     COLOR_WHITE       7     max,max,max
> ```

Putting this all together we can modify the existing `PS1` and `PS0` variables so that the colour is changed for the command input but restored before command execution:

```
OPS0="$PS0" OPS1="$PS1"                                       # Save originals
t7="$(tput setaf 7)" t6="$(tput setaf 6)"                     # White, Cyan
[[ -n "$PS1" ]] && PS0="\[$t7\]" PS1="\[$t7\]$PS1\[$t6\]"     # After and before command entry
```

If you don't like what you see you can restore the values (or simply start a new shell)

```
PS0="$OPS0" PS1="$OPS1"
```

When you're ready, add the lines to your `.bashrc` for permanent excitement.

Comment: Have added my current setup for PS1 (shown in my question).  Which colourises username, hostname, and the current working directory.

Comment: Doesn't matter what your `$PS1` is; this code will work with it regardless

Comment: Have appended \[\033[01;32m\] to the end of my current PS1.

Comment: Why would you do that instead of doing what I've recommended?

Comment: I am noticing some strange characters after doing ls.

Comment: Just try what I've suggested _before_ you adjust it for different colours