# echo not taking colour settings

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors

Have printed some text for useful directories in my bashrc
but the colour of the echo text is not being taken from the definition
of the dircolors.

In dircolors I have

```
NORMAL  01;32  # Bold Green  
FILE    01;37  # Bold White for regular files
RESET   0      # Reset to normal color
```

Here are my settings in my bashrc

```
PS1='\n\[\033[01;36m\]\u@\h:'   
PS1=$PS1'\n+ \[\033[38;5;214m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\n'

eval "$(dircolors -b ~/rcutils/dircolors)"
 
echo "Useful Directories:" 
echo "  cd ~/tdr"
```

Comment: Please format your script in [code format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), not as quotes; I can't figure out what it's supposed to do. But... are you expecting `echo` to colorize its output? It doesn't do that.

Comment: Does echo in terminal not take colour settings from dircolors setting of NORMAL ?

Comment: No, `echo` just prints text. It has no idea if the text contains file and/or directory names. `dircolors` sets the `LS_COLORS` variable, which is used by the `ls` command, and not much else.